# How to import PostgreSQL into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, import, dump

I have dumped a PostgreSQL database and I would need it to a MySQL as we migrate our project from Heroku to Amazon EC2, where is MySQL.

It's quite a long time when I was doing something similar like raw dumps & SQL queries, so I would like to ask you for help how to make this as smoothly as possible.

I dumped a PostgreSQL database. When I open the file, there are some PostgreSQL commands, table structures and data that belongs to those tables. On the other hand, I have on EC2 a MySQL database with created tables (the same tables as are in the PostgreSQL dump - but all MySQL tables are empty). My goal is to populate the MySQL tables with data from PostgreSQL tables.

How to do that?

Comment: Would help you use a tool to connect into postgree and generate an export script to mysql ?

Comment: Amazon EC2 also offers Postgres, fwiw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [migrate postgreSQL data to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303475/migrate-postgresql-data-to-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

As of 6 days ago Amazon started offering [a hosted PostgreSQL service](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/11/14/announcing-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/) as part of their Relational Database Service. I would seriously considering importing straight back into PostgreSQL and skipping MySQL altogether. Changing to a different DBMS is always more pain than it's worth.

You can import your dump by running it using psql, like this: `psql -f <backup_filename> <target_db>`. See [Amazon's docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html) for more

If you're really set on migrating to MySQL you can try a simple tool like [openDBcopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/) or something more comprehensive (and complicated) like [Talend Studio](http://www.talend.com/download/data-integration).

Answer (score 0):

If you have text file created by `pg_dump` then in this file you can see data from source database as `COPY` command or as series of `INSERT` commands. Both should be easy to import to any other database. Maybe you will have to change string representation of dates. `COPY` format is simply CSV and for this you will have to write import program, for example Jython: Python language that can work with JDBC drivers. With Jython you can easily parse CSV data and import it into destination database using JDBC `PreparedStatement` with proper `INSERT`.

If you have connection to both databases at once you can "pump" destination database using various tools. As Jython fan I simply use JDBC with code like:

```
insert_stmt.setObject(i, rs_in.getObject(i))
```

where `insert_stmt` is`prepareStatement()` with `INSERT...` and `rs_in` is record set of `executeQuery()`